# Run Batch from a method in a simple apex controller

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, scheduled-job

I want a apex batch that can autorun when called another apex controller.
I have tried with the apex batch code as below.
But not getting the point correctly to how to put the batchscheduler. Can someone help?

The link I followed is this one.
https://blog.internetcreations.com/2011/09/executing-batch-apex-in-sequence/

Created custom settings accordingly only. Nothing written as required for Scheduler. Please help me here.

Batch code:

```
global class CallBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Call_abv__c,Call_abv__r.Parent_Call_vod__c FROM Compliance_Incident_Transaction_abv__c where Compliance_Incident_abv__r.Status_abv__c=\'Open\'');
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Compliance_Incident_Transaction_abv__c> scope){

     Set<Id> CallMap= new Set<Id>();
        for (Call2_vod__c myContact : [select ID,Parent_call_vod__c from call2_vod__c where ID in:scope]) 
        {CallMap.add(mycontact.id);
         CallMap.add(mycontact.Parent_call_vod__c);
        system.debug('CallMap@'+CallMap);

        }
        List<Call2_vod__C> Call2_vod_master = new List<Call2_vod__C> (); 
        Call2_vod_master=[SELECT id, Name,Account_vod__c, Incident_Exists_Flag_abv__c, Is_Parent_Call_vod__c, Parent_Call_vod__c 
    FROM Call2_vod__c where id in :CallMap];

        for (Call2_vod__c C : Call2_vod_master )
        { c.Override_lock_vod__c=true;
          c.Incident_Exists_Flag_abv__c =true ;
        }

        update Call2_vod_master;



    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        BatchSchedule__c b = BatchSchedule__c.getOrgDefaults();
        DateTime n = datetime.now().addMinutes(5);
        String cron = '';

        cron += n.second();
        cron += ' ' + n.minute();
        cron += ' ' + n.hour();
        cron += ' ' + n.day();
        cron += ' ' + n.month();
        cron += ' ' + '?';
        cron += ' ' + n.year();

        b.scheduled_id__c = System.schedule('Batch 2', cron, new BatchScheduler2());

        update b;
    }

}
```

Comment: If you want batch 2 to start after batch 1, you can call batch 2 from finish method of batch 1 finish method using `Database.executbatch(..)`.

Comment: @javanoob I have only one batch at my requirement and I want to run that when a method called in a different apex controller. I need to start the schedule by that time only.

Comment: you can run the batch from your main class using Database.executbatch(..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply initiate the batch by inserting below in your apex class from where you want to execute a batch class. 
Id bid = Database.executeBatch(, );

e.g in your case it should be 
Id bid = Database.executeBatch(new CallBatch() , 200);